# Can not reconnect to instance via ssh in google cloud

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, tmux

I use google could for machine learning. It takes too much time for completing execution. So I use tmux for that so that I can detach and attach to the session.

But now when I restart my laptop and try to open ssh. It shows `An error occurred while communicating with the SSH server. Check the server and the network configuration.` (I did not stop the instance). Also when I restarted the instance as I have no other option to connect, the extrnal IP is also different.

This the sequence of what i did.

1)

`$tmux
$jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --no-browser &`

2)After starting the execution `tmux detach` (as execution requires 5 hr).

3)then shutdowned the laptop

4) after an hr when I restarted the laptop opened the google cloud platform and clicked the ssh beside the instance.

5) it gave following error
`An error occurred while communicating with the SSH server. Check the server and the network configuration`

So what happens than I can not use tmux attach as I can not open ssh window.

I have not used google cloud before,So i don't know if i am doing anything wrong here.

please help.

Comment: You can attach elastic IP to your instance, in order to make external IP static. Have u tried without tmux, I mean with a built-in shell with GCP provides?

Comment: Okay let me try without tmux, But If I am not wrong I can not  shut down the laptop after that, Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Yes, I guess, while your machine learning task is running through ssh.

Comment: It does not work execution stops after processing 8% file every time.

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with google cloud, I think tmux is not able to hold process after pc logout as these tools are to run process in background only, they dont deal  with SIGHUP. Can you run your jupyter command using nohup?

Comment: in my view nohup doesnt let process die after shell sends kill signal.

Answer (score 0):

First try stop and starting again the VM instance.

If that doesn't work try below.

Create the machine image for that instance, and create new instance using this machine image .N o data will be lost .You may need to restart the services deployed on VM.